# Web development for a user profile enabled website

Tags: relational-database, user-experience

I am developing a website that will contain user profiles with significant amount of their data. Beyond the general user profile information, I will also need to store their settings, interaction history with other users, and actions they've taken on my website(i.e. purchased an item).

I am largely unfamiliar with web development on an enterprise level. Is there a more efficient way to store user profiles than using a relational database (oracle, mysql, ingres, etc)? Obviously within that realm there are multiple optimizations possible, but outside the scope of a relational database, is there a more modern and better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a relational database for storing user profile and user activity information.

The "more modern solution" would be a non-relational database.  Such databases are good at storing large amounts of loosely structured information.

For well-structured transactional data like user profile and messages and purchases, relational database is the best choice.  RDBMS is designed specifically to efficiently store and retrieve well structured transactional data.

Answer (score 1):

No. How else do you want to store the user profiles and interactions without using a database? MySQL can be used for very small to large scale web applications plus it's free, has a wide support and its quite easy to learn.

I would suggest you use a DB. You can check out [Cloud Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing)

Comment: Why would you recommend cloud computing when there's perfectly good learning environments like XAMPP that don't cost a penny?